# Is it possible to update a DirectX SDK install?

Tags: directx

Is it possible to update a current install of the DirectX SDK, or is the only way to use the latest SDK to install the latest SDK in a new directory and delete the old one?

Specifically, if I have DirectX (March 2009), and the latest version is DirectX (August 2009), what choices do I have for getting the updated SDK without leaving the old SDK installed?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you care ?

Comment: @Bahbar - Each SDK install takes nearly a gigabyte of space.

Comment: why don't you just uninstall the SDK first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The install can live together, and install in separate space. You have to uninstall the old one, and install the new one, otherwise you'll use double space.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Seems I was wrong. Sorry.

I'm pretty sure an install of the new sdk will override the former sdk install. That means you only have to install DirectX(August 2009) and it should take care of the rest.

Comment: I just installed the latest SDK - it does indeed install to a new directory.